# regex_replace in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm not expert in a regular expressions, and in Oracle I want to find a string in a text using `regexp_replace(0` function.

The string to find has at beginning an "[" and at the end an "]".
Between "[" and "]", you will find letters and "_" characters.

So, if I have this text:

**the ID's are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3] ..... [tagN]**

how can I remove [ and ]?

I need to get

**the ID's are tag1 , tag2 , tag3 ...., tagN**

I tried this:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('the ID's are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3].........','[(.*?)]') from dual
```

but it's not working.

The field that contains the text is in a table with 1 millions of records at least.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: You say the substitute values are in another table? How are they stored? How do you map `[tag1]` to `221` and `[tag3]` to `13412`?

Comment: @jarlh oracle :)

Comment: You substantially changed your question after people had answered the original question. Poor show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' from dual
), t2(str2) as
(
 select regexp_substr(str,'[^\[]+', 1, 1) from t
)
select concat( regexp_substr(str,'[^\[]+', 1), 
         listagg(replace(regexp_substr(str,'[^\[]*.[^\]]', 1, level),']',''),',') 
              within group (order by 1) ) 
       as "Derived String"       
  from t 
 cross join t2 
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'\[');

Derived String
---------------------------
the ID's are tag1,tag2,tag3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/KNKX15075)</kbd>

**Edit 1**: *If you want to extract dynamically only the tags as*

`tag1 tag2 tag3 .... tag n`

then use below

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' from dual
)
select   listagg(replace(regexp_substr(str,'[^\[]*.[^\]]', 1, level),']',''),' ') 
              within group (order by 1) 
       as "Derived String"       
  from t  
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'\[')
```

**Edit 2** *(due to the last comment):*

Try using below

```
with t(a,b) as
(
 select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' as a,
        'the ID''s are [tag4] , [tag5] , [tag6], [tag7]' as b
   from dual
)
select   listagg(replace(regexp_substr(a,'[^\[]*.[^\]]', 1, level),']',''),' ') 
              within group (order by 1) 
       as "Derived String 1",
         listagg(replace(regexp_substr(b,'[^\[]*.[^\]]', 1, level),']',''),' ') 
              within group (order by 1) 
       as "Derived String 2"       
  from t  
 connect by level <= greatest(regexp_count(a,'\['),regexp_count(b,'\['));

Derived String 1                  Derived String 2
---------------------------       ---------------------------   
tag1 tag2 tag3                    tag4 tag5 tag6 tag7
```

Comment: what if we want only the tags? like tag1 tag2 tag3 ... tagN

Comment: what if the input is not a single column but different? like 
 select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' a,'the ID''s are [tag4] , [tag5] , [tag6]' b from dual??

Comment: @TheEliteOne The logic doesn't change. Just replace `str` twice with `a` and with `b` where our query is `select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' as a, 'the ID''s are [tag4] , [tag5] , [tag6]' as b from dual` returning "Derived String1" and "Derived String2".

Comment: you mean
with t(a,b) as
(
 select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' as a, 'the ID''s are [wer] , [re] , [werwer]' as b from dual
)
select   listagg(replace(regexp_substr(a,'[^\[]*.[^\]]', 1, level),']',''),', ') 
              within group (order by 1) 
       as "a"     
  from t  
  connect by level <= regexp_count(a,'\[') 

select   listagg(replace(regexp_substr(b,'[^\[]*.[^\]]', 1, level),']',''),', ') 
              within group (order by 1) 
       as "b"     
  from t  
  connect by level <= regexp_count(b,'\[')   ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to orignal question:

```
with s as (select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' str from dual)
select
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(str, '\[.*?\]', '221'  , 1, 1)
                                                , '\[.*?\]', '342'  , 1, 1)
                                                , '\[.*?\]', '13412', 1, 1) as str
from s;

STR
------------------------------
the ID's are 221 , 342 , 13412
```

Answer to changed question:

```
with s as (select 'the ID''s are [tag1] , [tag2] , [tag3]' str from dual)
select
replace(replace(str, ']'), '[') str
from s;

STR
-------------------------------
the ID's are tag1 , tag2 , tag3
```

Comment: Hello, thank's for the answer. really appreciate :) !

Answer (score 1):

Why not just replace the `[` and `]`?

```
select translate(text, 'x[]', 'x')
```